# PSTricks figure way too big; normal scaling seems not to work

Tags: pstricks, scaling

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\def\radius{19.2}
\def\lige{33.3}
\newlength\R \R=\radius\psunit
\newlength\hW \hW=\lige\psunit
\hW=0.5\hW
\centering
 \psset{
   unit=0.2,
   linewidth=1pt
 }
  \begin{pspicture}(-35.5,-18.9)(34.9,18.9)
   \psset{
     linecolor=red
   }
    \psarc( \hW,0){\R}{270}{90}
    \psarc(-\hW,0){\R}{90}{270}
    \psline(-\hW, \R)(\hW, \R)  
    \psline(-\hW,-\R)(\hW,-\R)
   \psset{
     linecolor=black,
     linestyle=dotted
   }
    \psline(-\hW,-\R)(-\hW,\R)
    \psline( \hW,-\R)( \hW,\R)
    \psline(\dimexpr-\hW-\R,0)(\dimexpr\hW+\R,0)
    \rput*(0,0){\lige\,cm}
    \rput*(\dimexpr-\hW-0.5\R,0){\radius\,cm}
    \rput*(\dimexpr \hW+0.5\R,0){\radius\,cm}
    \rput(-\hW,0){\textbf{+}}
    \rput( \hW,0){\textbf{+}}
  \end{pspicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The figure is way too big and changing the `unit` option apparently has no effect.

How do I fix this?

P.S. The figure used to have the right scale so I have obviously introduced something 'fishy' but I haven't got a clue as to what that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed your code contains a logical bug. The canvas size must be

```
(-\dimexpr\hW+\R,-\radius)(\dimexpr\hW+\R,\radius)
```

So now my answer has extra value. Why don't accept it? :-)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

\centering
 \psset{
   unit=0.2,
   linewidth=1pt
 }
\def\radius{19.2}
\def\lige{33.3}
\newlength\R \R=\radius\psunit
\newlength\hW \hW=\lige\psunit
\hW=0.5\hW
  \begin{pspicture}(-\dimexpr\hW+\R,-\radius)(\dimexpr\hW+\R,\radius)
   \psset{
     linecolor=red
   }
    \psarc( \hW,0){\R}{270}{90}
    \psarc(-\hW,0){\R}{90}{270}
    \psline(-\hW, \R)(\hW, \R)  
    \psline(-\hW,-\R)(\hW,-\R)
   \psset{
     linecolor=black,
     linestyle=dotted
   }
    \psline(-\hW,-\R)(-\hW,\R)
    \psline( \hW,-\R)( \hW,\R)
    \psline(\dimexpr-\hW-\R,0)(\dimexpr\hW+\R,0)
    \rput*(0,0){\lige\,cm}
    \rput*(\dimexpr-\hW-0.5\R,0){\radius\,cm}
    \rput*(\dimexpr \hW+0.5\R,0){\radius\,cm}
    \rput(-\hW,0){\textbf{+}}
    \rput( \hW,0){\textbf{+}}
  \end{pspicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to do the calculations on the Postscript side. This must be enabled with `\SpecialCoor`, and allows to access the `!` notation.

A simple addition then is done like in `\pnode(! 1 2 add 1){A}`, which is equivalent to `\plot(3, 1){A}`.

So your example could likewise be written as:

```
\documentclass[pstricks, border=3pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\def\radius{19.2}
\def\R{\radius\space}
\def\lige{33.3}
\def\hW{16.65 }

\SpecialCoor

 \psset{%
   unit=0.2,
   linewidth=1pt
 }%
  \begin{pspicture}(-35.5,-18.9)(34.9,18.9)
   \psset{linecolor=red}
    \psarc(\hW,0){\R}{270}{90}
    \psarc(-\hW,0){\R}{90}{270}
    \psline(-\hW, \R)(\hW, \R)  
    \psline(-\hW,-\R)(\hW,-\R)
   \psset{
     linecolor=black,
     linestyle=dotted
   }
    \psline(-\hW,-\R)(-\hW,\R)
    \psline( \hW,-\R)( \hW,\R)
    \psline(! -\hW \R sub 0)(!\hW \R add 0)
    \rput*(0, 0){\lige\,cm}
    \rput*(! -\hW -0.5 \R mul add 0){\R\,cm}
    \rput*(! \hW 0.5 \R mul add 0){\R\,cm}
    \rput(-\hW,0){\textbf{+}}
    \rput( \hW,0){\textbf{+}}
  \end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Note, that I defined `\R` as `\radius\space`, and explicitely left a space after the number in `\hW`, so one does not always have to write e.g. `(!\hW\space \radius\space add 0)` in order to get the required white spaces, but with the above definitions it writes as `(!\hw \R add)`.

Comment: Thank you. I was aware of the (type of) solution, too. (Note: It is actually `\def\hW{16.65 }` and not 50/3.

Comment: Unfortunately, PostScript expressions cannot be used to specify the canvas size.