# Not equal spacing on both sides of PSTricks figure

Tags: spacing, pstricks

Taking the code of PSTikZ's answer from "[PSTricks figure way too big; normal scaling seems not to work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132589/15874)" (and putting an `\fbox` around it to illustrate the problem), I get the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\psset{
  unit=0.2,
  linewidth=1pt
}
\def\radius{19.2}
\def\lige{33.3}
\newlength\R \R=\radius\psunit
\newlength\hW \hW=\lige\psunit
\hW=0.5\hW
 \centering
\fbox{%
  \begin{pspicture}(-\dimexpr\hW+\R,-\radius)(\dimexpr\hW+\R,\radius)
   \psset{
     linecolor=red
   }
    \psarc( \hW,0){\R}{270}{90}
    \psarc(-\hW,0){\R}{90}{270}
    \psline(-\hW, \R)(\hW, \R)  
    \psline(-\hW,-\R)(\hW,-\R)
   \psset{
     linecolor=black,
     linestyle=dotted
   }
    \psline(-\hW,-\R)(-\hW,\R)
    \psline( \hW,-\R)( \hW,\R)
    \psline(\dimexpr-\hW-\R,0)(\dimexpr\hW+\R,0)
    \rput*(0,0){\lige\,cm}
    \rput*(\dimexpr-\hW-0.5\R,0){\radius\,cm}
    \rput*(\dimexpr \hW+0.5\R,0){\radius\,cm}
    \rput(-\hW,0){\textbf{+}}
    \rput( \hW,0){\textbf{+}}
  \end{pspicture}
}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Why is there more space on the right hand side of the figure than on the left?

P.S. This is a universal problem/"feature" of PSTricks pictures.

Comment: it has _nothing_ to do with PSTricks! `\fbox{a }` is the same.

Comment: I agree with Herbert, I don't notice any gap. See my answer but I rewritten your code using `standalone` and some minor changes in coding style.

Comment: @Herbert Yes, Gonzalo Medina told me what causes the extra space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a spurious blank space after `\end{pspicture}`; remove it (for example, by commenting it out):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\psset{
  unit=0.2,
  linewidth=1pt
}
\def\radius{19.2}
\def\lige{33.3}
\newlength\R \R=\radius\psunit
\newlength\hW \hW=\lige\psunit
\hW=0.5\hW
 \centering
\fbox{%
  \begin{pspicture}(-\dimexpr\hW+\R,-\radius)(\dimexpr\hW+\R,\radius)
   \psset{
     linecolor=red
   }
    \psarc( \hW,0){\R}{270}{90}
    \psarc(-\hW,0){\R}{90}{270}
    \psline(-\hW, \R)(\hW, \R)  
    \psline(-\hW,-\R)(\hW,-\R)
   \psset{
     linecolor=black,
     linestyle=dotted
   }
    \psline(-\hW,-\R)(-\hW,\R)
    \psline( \hW,-\R)( \hW,\R)
    \psline(\dimexpr-\hW-\R,0)(\dimexpr\hW+\R,0)
    \rput*(0,0){\lige\,cm}
    \rput*(\dimexpr-\hW-0.5\R,0){\radius\,cm}
    \rput*(\dimexpr \hW+0.5\R,0){\radius\,cm}
    \rput(-\hW,0){\textbf{+}}
    \rput( \hW,0){\textbf{+}}
  \end{pspicture}%
}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! So, to get the correct position of the `pspicture`, I should always put a `%` right after `\end{pspicture}`?

Comment: @SvendTveskæg no; not always, just when spurious blank spaces might need to be removed.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I don't notice any gap with your re-written code below.

To easily locate the peculiarity, it is better to put each your diagram in a single compilable input as follows.

```
% your-diagram.tex
\documentclass[pstricks,border=0.5pt]{standalone}
\def\radius{19.2}
\def\lige{33.3}

\psset
{
    unit=0.2,
    linewidth=1pt,
}

\newlength\R
\newlength\hW  

\R=\radius\psunit
\hW=\lige\psunit
\hW=0.5\hW

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-\dimexpr\hW+\R,-\radius)(\dimexpr\hW+\R,\radius)
    \psset
    {
        linecolor=red,
    }
    \psarc(\hW,0){\R}{270}{90}
    \psarc(-\hW,0){\R}{90}{270}
    \psline(-\hW,\R)(\hW,\R)
    \psline(-\hW,-\R)(\hW,-\R)
    \psset
    {
        linecolor=black,
        linestyle=dotted,
    }
    \psline(-\hW,-\R)(-\hW,\R)
    \psline(\hW,-\R)(\hW,\R)
    \psline(\dimexpr-\hW-\R,0)(\dimexpr\hW+\R,0)
    \rput*(0,0){\lige\,cm}
    \rput*(\dimexpr-\hW-\R/2,0){\radius\,cm}
    \rput*(\dimexpr\hW+\R/2,0){\radius\,cm}
    \rput(-\hW,0){\textbf{+}}
    \rput(\hW,0){\textbf{+}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Compile it with `latex->dvips-ps2pdf` sequence to get a PDF output.

[image]

From your main input file, you can import the PDF image with `\includegraphics` from `graphicx` package.

```
% main-input-file.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{your-diagram}
\caption{Your diagram in action}
\label{fig:your-diagram}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Advantages of separation of concern method:

- You can notice, find, and solve any peculiarities, errors, etc easily.
- You can reuse your diagram for other projects.
- Your main input file becomes cleaner and tidier.
- The compilation time can be significantly reduced as you don't have to recompile the unchanged diagrams.

Comment: Isn't it a little bit tautological to suppress the problem and then say that you don't notice it? ;-)